# ObjectListView add a few buttons into a cell

Tags: button, cell, objectlistview

Is it possible to add more than 1 button into a cell (Table view)?
E.g. to make Actions column with three different buttons for the needed actions.

I know that IsButton lets to put a button into a cell, but how about a few ones?

Thank you!